# Java using static method as overridden method

Tags: java, object, static, overriding

I know Its not supported, unlike in php. Let me draft my system.

Its a 2D scrolling game, with object (Cloud, Star, Bird), with a common, "BaseItem" class. Different things can happen on collision with them, getting more life, losing a life... etc. An abstract method, BaseItem.eventOnCollation() would only return an array describing what changed (got a life, lost a life, got a bonus etc).

So far so good, but there is another "CloudB" with the same effect as "Cloud". Copy exactly the eventOnCollation() method? Code repetition. Instatinize "Cloud" and call its eventOnLocation()? Better, but the instatize loads more, unnecessary things. I just want to know what the effect is on collate.

Thats when I said lets use static - its not even needed to have an instance of an object to know its effect - there can be 100 Stars with the same effect.
The objects are in a Vector. And this is when I iterate all object, and would call the eventOnCollation() - exception!

I hope it was all clear

Comment: "*I hope it was all clear*" => not really... This type of thing is best explained with actual code rather than words.

Comment: Static methods have noting to do with overriding , they are for different purpose altogether.

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: then imagine something like SuperMario :)

Comment: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expecting non-static method _BaseItem.effectOnCollation()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make CloudB extend Cloud and override all methods except `eventOnLocation()`.
No `static`here.

Comment: yea. But then constructor Cloud is also called, which should be skipped. Something like super.super :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use static methods for behavior you mentioned.
What you probably want to do, is to make `CloudB` extend `Cloud`:

```
public class CloudB extends Cloud { ... }
```

Then you can use all the nice things like overriding methods, abstract methods, etc... to have different behavior for similar classes without code duplication.

Comment: yea. But then constructor Cloud is also called, which should be skipped. Something like super.super :)